# "commit your changes before" tras un conflicto

Tags: git, conflictos

Intenté hacer un `git cherry-pick`, pero falló con un conflicto:

```
$ git cherry-pick master
error: could not apply 456190d... Mejoro el post
hint: after resolving the conflicts, mark the corrected paths
hint: with 'git add <paths>' or 'git rm <paths>'
hint: and commit the result with 'git commit'
```

Me faltaba `merge`ar algunos commits previos para poder `cherry-pick`ear ese último, y entonces hice `reset` para deshacer los cambios y poder aplicar el `merge`:

```
$ git status --short
DU source/images/uploads/2016/review.png
$ git reset .
$ git status --short
?? source/images/uploads/2016/review.png
$ git clean -fd
Removing source/images/uploads/2016/review.png
```

Pero el `merge` falla:

```
$ git merge origin/stable 
fatal: You have not concluded your cherry-pick (CHERRY_PICK_HEAD exists).
Please, commit your changes before you merge.
```

**¿Cuál es la forma correcta de solucionar el conflicto?**

Se que puedo hacer `rm .git/CHERRY_PICK_HEAD` y esquivar el problema, pero imagino que habrá una forma más *correcta* de hacerlo.

Comment: sabes que archivos están en conflicto?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

La forma es

```
git cherry-pick --abort
```

esto revierte el repositorio al estado anterior.

Esta opción esta disponible desde la version 1.7.8, de mediados del 2013.

Answer (score 1):

Después de resolver un conflicto en los comandos rebase y cherry-pick, tienes que indicarle a Git que el conflicto está resuelto. En el  caso de cherry-pick, el comando es el siguiente:

```
git cherry-pick --continue
```

Después de esto, ya no tendrías problemas para realizar el merge

Comment: Justo en este caso quería evitar el `cherry-pick`, por lo que marqué [la respuesta de rnrenverdies](http://es.stackoverflow.com/a/2738/75) como correcta, pero también es útil saber de este comando.